# css display:block will not render a div area as visable on @media screen width change

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

menu1 text is displayed on page load and disappears just fine when changing screen width but menu2 text is never displayed (display:block)?

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Demo</title>
<!-- css3-mediaqueries.js for IE8 or older -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
 @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 #menu1   { display:none;  }
 #menu2   { display:block; }
}
#menu2    { display:none;  }
</style>
</head>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="menu1">menu1</div>
  <div id="menu2">menu2</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, media queries need to fall below the normal state of the element to override the styling; therefore, you should reverse the order to:

```
#menu2    { display:none;  }

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 #menu1   { display:none;  }
 #menu2   { display:block; }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mywzzp29/)

Its the same with any css styles (or fallback styles). The last style to be called is the style that takes precedence. If that style's requirements do not apply, the next style of the same property will (and so-on).